# Can I automatically map chrome's bookmarks bar to its jump list?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, jumplist

I would like the contents of my bookmarks bar to be present in my Google Chrome jump list, without the manual tedium of managing both the bar's organization and contents and those of the jump list.  If it's possible to automatically manage jump lists in such a way as to make this possible, I'd be delighted.  I don't think I'm quite ready to attempt programming an extension thus myself.

edit:  it appears this is not possible.  I have submitted the feature as a request to the chrome team.

Comment: I think someone should add this great idea to https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/chrome/give-feature-feedback-and-suggestions . In comparison, Opera puts its SpeedDial sites on its jumplist http://files.myopera.com/jdlien/blog/JumpList2.png . Firefox, Safari and IE9, no.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the free [Jumplist Extender](http://code.google.com/p/jumplist-extender/) described as :

> easy-to-use program that lets you add custom jump lists to any of your
>   programs on Windows 7
>
> With Jumplist Extender, you can:
>
> - Add your own Program Tasks
> - Pin Any Type of File
> - Create Extensions to your Programs
> - Share your Jumplists with Others

(Note: I have no personal experience with this product.)

Comment: I'm sorry, I checked this out, but I already know that even without it, I could manually pin pages to the jump list, and I've even checked out the chrome bookmarks file, which is rendered in XML.  But I don't want to do this manually, and I was wondering if there's a program to add the contents of the XML bookmarks file to the jump list, not so much add new jump-list activities corresponding to hotkeys or command line arguments.  This is cool, but it's not what I want.

Comment: You might try to drag bookmarks from Chrome to Jumplist Extender (not using Chrome, so cannot test).